# Vector Arc Length

Tags: geometry, vectors

For example, in a unit circle, let $O(0,1)$ be the original point, what is the arc length (counter-clockwise, not the shortest arc length) from $O$ to point $P\left(\cos(t),\sin(t)\right)$.

I am trying to use vector additions to find the chord length and then finding its arc length. However this gives me the shortest arc length as I am only taking the magnitude of the chord length. Is there any solutions?

Here is what I mean if it helps:
[image]

Comment: Do you know integration? For a parametrized curve $\varphi$, the length is $\int_a^b|\varphi'(t)|dt$, (which turns out extremely simply in this case)

Comment: Alternatively, consider the very definition of radians

Comment: @Milten, thanks for the comment. I am familiar with integration but not parametrization. Are you able to elaborate a bit more on the two methods you suggested?

Comment: See vectorially, you are getting $2sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{t}{2})$ as the chord length.

Comment: @GauravMishra Thanks, are you able to show me how you got this equation? If this gives the counter-clockwise chord length, "vectorially," then finding its arc length should be no problem.

Comment: See let's say Q is the origin then in your diagram $\vec {QO}+\vec {OP}=\vec{QP}$
then $\hat j+\vec {OP}=cost \hat i+sint\hat j$ Now $\vec {QP}=cost \hat i+(sint-1)\hat j$, then magnitude of this will be $|2sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{t}{2})|$

Comment: @GauravMishra Should it be OQ+QP = OP instead?

Comment: Yes that was a typing error earlier but you can see your diagram see what i have writtem. It doesn't matter earlier i took sint positive but as in your diagram it was negative so $\vec {QO}+\vec {OP}=\vec{QP}$
then $\hat j+\vec {OP}=cost \hat i-sint\hat j$ Now $\vec {QP}=cost \hat i-(sint+1)\hat j$, then magnitude of this will be $|2sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{t}{2})|$

Comment: @GauravMishra Thank you

Comment: @Milten how does your integral formula work here?

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$t'=t-2\pi\left\lfloor\frac{t}{2\pi}\right\rfloor.$$
Then $(\cos t' , \sin t')=(\cos t , \sin t)$ are the same points on the unit circle. And we can show that $0\leq t' <2\pi$. Therefore, the length of the counter-clockwise arc from $O=(1,0)$ to $P$ is equal to $t'$.

**Example**: Let $t=-\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Then
$$t'=-\frac{3\pi}{2}-2\pi\left\lfloor\frac{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}{2\pi}\right\rfloor=-\frac{3\pi}{2}-2\pi\left\lfloor-\frac{3}{4}\right\rfloor=\frac{3\pi}{2}-2\pi(-1)=-\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

OP took $O=(0,1)$. In that case the answer will be
$$t''=t-\frac{\pi}{2}-2\pi\left\lfloor\frac{t-\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\pi}\right\rfloor$$
by a translation. Right?

Comment: Note that $O$ is inconveniently not $(1,0)$, but $(0,1)$, so you need to offset the answer.